# how to bind names between text box to label

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can i bind values from shown single text box to label value ??
If i use ng-repeat in this i'm facing issues to my further functionalities.. can u pls solve this issue. i'm not able to bind between them ....[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiAJNluHC30BznMemhWn?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.my = {name: 'untitled'};
  var counter=0;
  $scope.add_Name = function(index) {
    var myName='untitled'+counter;
    var namehtml = '<label ng-click="selectName(\''+myName+'\')">'+myName+' //click<br/></label>';
    var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(name);
    ++counter;
  };

  $scope.selectName = function(val) {
    
    $scope.my.name=val;
    $scope.showName = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add_Name($index)">Add Names</button>
 <div id="add"></div><br/>

 <form ng-show="showName">
      <label>Name Change(?)</label><br/>
   <input ng-model="my.name">
 </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: _i'm facing issues to my further functionalities_ means?

Comment: Did you mean by change the input box label text right

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd .. i wanted to save names in different forms, if i opened saved form it was showing invisible, if i enter names again it was adding names multiple times.. that type of issue i'm having if i use ng-repeat in div.. can u pls solve this issue to me..  tnx in advance ..

Comment: yeah right @Sathiyaraj .. :)

Comment: Please place your issue code not plunker example code. So I can able to issue and solution.

Comment: Please write proper problem descriptions and provide expected behaviors

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i updated my code.. can u pls check it once.. i want to bind values from  input text to label name using append event ....

Comment: @charlietfl i updated my code using ng-repeat.. but how can i change each name without using ng-repeat either jquery or javascript, if it's not possible in angularjs..

Comment: what does `change each name` mean? Also there is no `$index` except in `ng-repeat`. Not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl .. means if i did append 2names, i want to give 2different names to that appended names...

Comment: @charlietfl i updated my answer using ng-repeat, and i used $index .. but how can i give $index in append event ...

Comment: @charlietfl .. i tried using ng-repeat and $index.. i get the result, but when i'm going to save the form.. it was showing null data in the form,, if i use append it was showing data perfectly.. that is why i am trying to solve this issue using append event,, but not getting result,, can u pls tell me how to solve this ...

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd .. HI, have u understood my issue ?

Comment: This question is getting put together in bits and pieces. I have no idea what `append` you are talking about and the question doesn't explain what this code is supposed to be doing. To add items to ng-repeat you push a new item to the data model array. You don't manipulate the dom yourself..let angular do that part. In the futire please add the details needed to questions so we all know what should be happening and what isn't working properly and use full sentences

Comment: @charlietfl .. https://jsbin.com/jejeruvupi/edit?html,js,output .. follow this link, what u r telling is this is correct way to get exact result, isn't it ??

Comment: basically yes that's how you do it

Comment: @charlietfl .. there is 2ways to add data using **ng-repeat** and **append** using ng-repeat i'm getting exact result, but there is some issues to my further functionalities, another way is **append** to add names,, this is perfectly giving result without any issues,, but i'm not able to change names.. i don't know how to solve that,, i know only using ng-repeat.. do u know how to change?? if u can solve this issue to me .. thank you in advance ... :)

Comment: Try `$scope.names.push($scope.currentEdit); $scope.currentEdit={}//reset`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100448/discussion-between-vijju-sena-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code, here's a working version, finally i got the result:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.my = {name: 'untitled'};
  $scope.mies=[]; // added an array to store the generated values
  var counter=0;
  $scope.add_Name = function(index) {
    $scope.mies[counter]={name: 'untitled'+counter}; // insert a new object into the array
    var namehtml = '<label ng-click="selectName(mies[\''+counter+'\'])">{{mies['+counter+'].name}} //click<br/></label>';
    var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(name);
    ++counter;
  };

  $scope.selectName = function(val) {
    
    $scope.my=val; // set my to val instead of my.name
    $scope.showName = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add_Name($index)">Add Names</button>
 <div id="add"></div><br/>

 <form ng-show="showName">
      <label>Name Change(?)</label><br/>
   <input ng-model="my.name">
 </form>
  </body>

</html>
```